# Rails: sharing eco templates between Ruby and JavaScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eco

I understand sharing templates between Ruby and JavaScript can be done in Rails (as seen in [Railscast #295](http://railscasts.com/episodes/295-sharing-mustache-templates)). There is something about Mustache that I don't like, though.

I would love to accomplish this using eco ([Embedded CoffeeScript](https://github.com/sstephenson/eco)).

I created the eco template handler in `config/initializers/eco_template_handler.rb`:

```
module EcoTemplateHandler
  def self.call(template)
    Eco.render(template.source.inspect, template.locals)
  end
end
ActionView::Template.register_template_handler(:eco, EcoTemplateHandler)
```

Which will allow me to render .eco files from within the server templates (i.e., `<%= render 'form' %>` will render _form.html.eco). However, this is only half of the equation.

According to [some](http://www.coffeescriptlove.com/2011/10/eco-templates-in-rails-31-asset.html) people ([and more](http://stjhimy.com/posts/28-javascript-templates-using-eco)), you need to use JST for eco to work in JavaScript templates. I'm not too familiar with JST.

Is this possible? Has anyone been able to accomplish this?